# How do i use Url by using ajax in yii?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

**View Page**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#project").change(function(){
             var data1=$("#project").val();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('ajaxfunc'); ?>",
       data: {id:data1},
       success:function(data2){alert(data2);},
       error: function(data2) {alert("Error occured.please try again");
             alert(data2)},
      });
    });
     </script>
```

**Controllerpage(Name:TaskController)**

```
public function accessRules()
        {
            return array(
                    array('allow', 
                    'actions'=>array('admin','delete','ajaxfunc'),
                    'users'=>array('admin'),
                ),

            );
        }

     public function actionAjaxfunc($id){
            echo "test";
           Yii::app()->end();
     }
```

I am using the Yii framework with PHP. I need to pass value to controller by using Ajax. But in the above code giving error message only. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use controller name then action in url -

```
url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('task/ajaxfunc'); ?>",
```

and in `accessRules()`, you have assigned this action to admin..if any user can access this, then use *

```
'users'=>array('*'),
```

Comment: i had add controller name ('task/ajaxfunc'). but nothing happen.same error message will be display